# Why is the Exchange Web Service API unable to delete a mail from the mailbox?

Tags: java, web-services, exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange Web Services API (v2.0) to process emails from a mailbox and then using the below line to move them to the deleted items folder.

`EmailMessage.delete(DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems);`

This was working fine all along and now, it gives me the below exception:

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.internalThrowIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:278)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.throwIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:267)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:165)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalDeleteItems(ExchangeService.java:1429)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.deleteItem(ExchangeService.java:1469)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.internalDelete(Item.java:226)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.delete(Item.java:348)
```

There has been no change on the mailbox configuration and I am unable to figure what might have caused this to happen all of a sudden. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the jar file version of the corresponding library? Is it updated under the hood?

Comment: @Steephen Verified this, it remains the same.

Comment: can you delete the item though OWA yourself. That error is indicating the server can't delete the message which maybe due to issue in the Mailbox (eg over quota etc)

Comment: I am able to do both Soft-delete and Hard-delete from the OWA. The mailbox says there is about 5+ GB size.